# MVVM design trouble

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, mvvm

My problem is operating with a list and a listview. The Listview's itemsSource property is bound to a list in my class(say List).

I want to both modify existing items and add new items to the list. For this reason, I've made text boxes for each element in the class Contact(name, surname, ...)

Now If I want to modify the selected item, I set the Text property of each textbox to this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listView1, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
```

If I want to create new element. I've got to do this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=tempContact, Path=Name}"/>
```

where tempContact is an instance of the Contact class that is lately added to the list via a button.

Problem is I want to do both adding and modifying the elements of this list and I need an idea. Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Are you using an `ObservableCollection`? Unless I don't understand I believe that will solve your problem.

Comment: I use a List, but I could also use ObservableCollection. How would that help?

Comment: Yeah, and `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the ViewModel.  That should get you going.

Comment: Could the new element add to the listView1 and select the added item first?

Comment: Rhyous I'm open to any ideas, only one I have now is using pointers, but I think everything else is better so please write show me what you have :)

@John Kalberer I use this already

Comment: @John: well, `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not enough, you need something like `INotifyCollectionChanged` for the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an item to list from `TextBox`, create a property of string type in your `ViewModel` and notify when the property changes. You have to create a similar property for edit too and also to store current index of selected item from the `ListView`

```
string contactName;
public string ContactName
{
    get 
    {
       return contactName; 
    }
    set 
    {
       contactName = value; 
       OnPropertyChanged("ContactName");
    }
}

private string editedName;
public string EditedName
{
    get { return editedName; }
    set
    {
        editedName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EditedName");
    }
}

private int selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return selectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        selectedIndex = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
    }
}
```

Add `TextBoxe`s and `ListBox` to your view and apply bindings. This is the tricky part. Because, when you choose an item from the `ListView`, index of the selected item has to be stored in the SelectedIndex property, selected contact name should be bound to the `TextBox` used to edit the value.

```
<ListBox  Name="contactNames" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding EditedName}" />
<TextBox Name="addNameTextBox" Text="{Binding ContactName}" />
<TextBox Name="editNameTextBox" Text="{Binding EditedName}" />
```

In the Command method that handles the button click, add logic to add or edit an item based on the properties set.

```
if (EditedName != null && EditedName != string.Empty)
{                
    ContactNames[SelectedIndex] = EditedName;
    EditedName = string.Empty;
}
else if (ContactName!=null && ContactName != string.Empty)
{
    ContactNames.Add(ContactName);
    ContactName = string.Empty;
}
```

Don't forget to create your list as an `ObservableCollection`. Otherwise, the `LisView` will not be notified about the changes made to list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I pretty much described this for adding an item in the collection. What I ask for is a method to both add AND edit

Comment: Thanks for that :). I too need sometime as I am a bit busy now

Answer (score 1):

I would add to your ViewModel a property that is the currently edited object. Then, in your ViewModel create a command to add to the list. For example, NewObjectCommand. In this command, you would toggle a state (maybe a boolean) that you were currently Editing a "new item", create the new object. Your EditedObject property would return the currently selected object in the list if you weren't adding a new object and return the new item being edited if you were adding.

When the state changes and the logical value of the EditedObject property can change, you will need to raise the PropertyChanged event on INotifiyPropertyChanged interface for the binding to update. You should bind your View containing the controls to edit your object to the EditedObject property of the ViewModel and make sure the ListBox is bound to the ViewModel's list and that the ViewModel can track the currently selected object in the list.

You'll have to figure out what trigger mechanism causes the object to be added to the list, and then you'll have to change the state back to the selected item after adding it. You'll probably need some validation logic as well with IDataErrorInfo or some such

Long Story Short:

- Create a state variable in your ViewModel
- Expose the EditedObject as a property; it returns the new object if one is being added, else the currently selected item in the list
- Bind to that

Comment: 1.How would the property get the currently selected item in the list, How would you bind to that? A few lines as an example and i'll be grateful! :)

Comment: @John you could just create a SelectedItem property in your ViewModel and bind ListBox.SelectedItem to it. Does that work for you? Otherwise, I'm sorta new to this too, but I believe you can create a CollectionView in your ViewModel and have your ListBox bind to it instead of using the default view. Then you can do sorting, filtering, etc as well as get the current index (from the collection view). when you bind directly to a collection a default view is automatically created for you.